# PHP: encrypt string in one page and decrypt it in another using POST?

Tags: php, encryption

I'm trying to encrypt a string in one php page and pass it to another page using $_POST[] and decrypt it again.

The encryption works fine but when I POST it to another page to decrypt it, it doesn't get decrypted at all and I get another encrypted string again!

**This is the code on page 1 where I encrypt:**

```
<?php
/*
 * PHP mcrypt - Basic encryption and decryption of a string
 */
$string = "somemails@yahoo.co.uk";
$secret_key = "This is my secret key";

// Create the initialization vector for added security.
$iv = mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB), MCRYPT_RAND);

// Encrypt $string
$encrypted_string = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $secret_key, $string, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);

// Decrypt $string
$decrypted_string = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $secret_key, $encrypted_string, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);

echo "Original string : " . $string . "<br />\n";
echo "Encrypted string : " . $encrypted_string . "<br />\n";
echo "Decrypted string : " . $decrypted_string . "<br />\n";
?>

<form action="2.php" method="post">
<input type="text" id="" name="input" value="<?php echo $encrypted_string; ?>"/>
<button type="submit" >submit</button>
</form>
```

**And this is the code in page 2 where I'm trying to decrypt again:**

```
<?php
    $input = $_POST['input'];

    $secret_key = "This is my secret key";

// Create the initialization vector for added security.
$iv = mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB), MCRYPT_RAND);

// Encrypt $string
$encrypted_string = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $secret_key, $input, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);

// Decrypt $string
$decrypted_string = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $secret_key, $encrypted_string, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);


echo $decrypted_string;
?>
```

Could someone please advise on this issue? is what i'm trying to do even possible?

Comment: mcrypt_create_iv uses MCRYPT_MODE_ECB and mcrypt_encrypt,mcrypt_decrypt uses MCRYPT_MODE_CBC....Try using any one of them!

Comment: Note that you're storing unauthenticated ciphertext on the client, which makes your form vulnerable to chosen-ciphertext attacks. Please don't roll your own; check out [defuse's library](https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption) instead. (It's MIT licensed.)

Comment: @ScottArciszewski, I ended up going with `BLOWFISH`

Comment: Why blowfish instead of defuse? Blowfish isn't authenticated.

Comment: @ScottArciszewski, i don't really need to authenticate the value! I just needed a way to encrypt the `$variable` so the users can't see it in the browser as it is in a hidden html input and then decrypt it again on the next page.

Comment: [Read this](https://tonyarcieri.com/all-the-crypto-code-youve-ever-written-is-probably-broken).

Comment: what is it? it says 'This site can’t provide a secure connection'!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe the following line:

```
$iv = mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB), MCRYPT_RAND);
```

It generates random IV everytime you call it. So you need to use same IV as you have used to encrypt it. So I suggest you to post the IV value too or use a specific IV instead such as:

```
$iv = "My Secret IV"; //On both pages
```

Comment: That worked like a charm and it decrypts the value in the second page but i get this error on both pages: `Warning: mcrypt_encrypt() [function.mcrypt-encrypt]: The IV parameter must be as long as the blocksize `

Comment: Try sending the IV using POST instead of using your own IV.

Comment: I did try sending it as a POST but that doesn't work and I get an encrypted string again on the second page but when I use my own "Secret IV", it works on the second page but I get that error on both pages 1 and 2.

Comment: Actually, Mangesh is right (in the comments), you are using two modes, try only one mcrypt mode.